# What are the reasons why a regresion prediction with a threshold cannot be used as classification?

Tags: regression, logistic, classification

For example, lets assume there are two models:

1. A logistic regression for whether or not it will rain the next day
2. A linear regression for the amount of rainfall tomorrow

What are the reason why and problems with using the prediction from the linear regression and applying a threshold value (>0) to it instead of using a logistic regression to predict whether or not it will rain.

Comment: Do you mean using a vector of $0$s and $1$s as your $y$ for the $\hat{\beta}_{\text{ols}}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ estimate?

Comment: Nope, using the level values of rainfall in mm, estimate a linear regression model. Then using the model to predict rainfall and applying a threshold value to the prediction (if predicted value is >0 then 1 otherwise 0. I guess the main thing is that you don't get any uncertainty about the outcome vs a logistic regression which give you the probability of the outcome as a prediction.

Comment: For one, you would have predictions < 0. Also, you fit the model for one purpose (amount of rain) and use it for something different. Therefore, even though the two questions are closely related, they are not the same and different models & variables might be optimal for prediction of each.

Comment: Predictions of <0 are not as much of a concern as this is a more general question (so instead of rainfall we can say wind speed and predict if it's a northerly wind as another example). I think I sort of answered my question with the fact that a logistic gives you the probability of that event happening.